# How to access detailed Java EE application deployment status on JBoss AS 7?

Tags: java, jakarta-ee, jboss7.x

Im trying to write a small "watchdog" *.war that monitors the deployment state of my (much larger) *.ear on jboss 7.1.3

How do I get at the *exact* deployment state of the *.ear?

I know I can do this (using jboss MSC classes):

```
ServiceContainer sc = CurrentServiceContainer.getServiceContainer(); //jboss msc
ServiceController earController = sc.getService(Services.deploymentUnitName("my.ear"));
return "my.ear - "+earController.getMode()+"-"+earController.getState()+"-"+earController.getSubstate();
```

but this will give me the all-green even if deployment failed. for exmaple - say I have a @Startup @Singleton, who's @PostConstruct method (called as part of boot) throws an exception. at this point my deployment has logically failed (initialization threw an exception) yet jboss will mark the *.ear as deployed - both using the marker files in the deployment directory (*.isDeploying --> *.deployed) and using the values from the controller above.

jboss does have a ContainerStateMonitor class that keeps a list of services with missing dependencies which is just what I need - any @Singletons that fails to start will cause a bunch of @EJBs that rely on it to fail to deploy - but I have no idea how to get at it.

the closest I found was this:

```
sc.getService(org.jboss.as.serverServices.JBOSS_SERVER_CONTROLLER).getService()
```

this gets me an instance of [ServerService](https://github.com/wildfly/wildfly/blob/master/server/src/main/java/org/jboss/as/server/ServerService.java) that has a controller (transient) field which holds that data. but its all in private fields and I really dont want to resort to reflection.

so my question is - is there any way to get at that data? jboss obviously knows what @Singletons failed to deploy, what @EJBs are missing dependencies, what datasources failed to connect etc, but is there a way for me to get to it? doesnt have to be MSC, could be JMX (though I think that just maps to MSC in jboss 7) or any other API.

Answer (score 3):

You could use the [management API](https://docs.jboss.org/author/display/AS71/Management+API+reference) and check the results.

The code would look something like:

```java
import java.net.InetAddress;

import org.jboss.as.controller.client.ModelControllerClient;
import org.jboss.as.controller.client.helpers.ClientConstants;
import org.jboss.as.controller.client.helpers.Operations;
import org.jboss.dmr.ModelNode;

public class ClientExample {

    public static void main(final String[] args) throws Exception {
        final ModelControllerClient client = ModelControllerClient.Factory.create(InetAddress.getLocalHost(), 9999);
        try {
            final ModelNode address = new ModelNode().setEmptyList();
            address.add("deployment", "jboss-as-helloworld.war");
            final ModelNode op = Operations.createReadResourceOperation(address, true);
            op.get(ClientConstants.INCLUDE_RUNTIME).set(true);
            final ModelNode outcome = client.execute(op);
            if (Operations.isSuccessfulOutcome(outcome)) {
                System.out.println(outcome);
            } else {
                System.err.printf("Operation failure: %s%n", Operations.getFailureDescription(outcome));
            }
        } finally {
            client.close();
        }
    }
}
```

Note I am using the 7.2.0.Final version of the API which should work with older versions of JBoss AS7, JBoss EAP 6.x and WildFly.

This outputs a result like

```
{
    "outcome" => "success",
    "result" => {
        "content" => [{"hash" => bytes {
            0xab, 0x77, 0x61, 0x49, 0x4b, 0x30, 0x3b, 0x4f,
            0xd7, 0x80, 0x13, 0x5a, 0x6c, 0x48, 0x1e, 0x3d,
            0xb3, 0xbe, 0xc1, 0xc2
        }}],
        "enabled" => true,
        "name" => "jboss-as-helloworld.war",
        "persistent" => true,
        "runtime-name" => "jboss-as-helloworld.war",
        "status" => "OK",
        "subdeployment" => undefined,
        "subsystem" => {"web" => {
            "active-sessions" => 0,
            "context-root" => "/jboss-as-helloworld",
            "duplicated-session-ids" => 0,
            "expired-sessions" => 0,
            "max-active-sessions" => 0,
            "rejected-sessions" => 0,
            "session-avg-alive-time" => 0,
            "session-max-alive-time" => 0,
            "sessions-created" => 0,
            "virtual-host" => "default-host",
            "servlet" => {"org.jboss.as.quickstarts.helloworld.HelloWorldServlet" => {
                "load-time" => 0L,
                "maxTime" => 9223372036854775807L,
                "min-time" => 0L,
                "processingTime" => 0L,
                "requestCount" => 0,
                "servlet-class" => "org.jboss.as.quickstarts.helloworld.HelloWorldServlet",
                "servlet-name" => "org.jboss.as.quickstarts.helloworld.HelloWorldServlet"
            }}
        }}
    }
}
```

Or if you just want the status you could change the above example slightly and do:

```java
final ModelNode op = Operations.createReadAttributeOperation(address, "status");
final ModelNode outcome = client.execute(op);
if (Operations.isSuccessfulOutcome(outcome)) {
    System.out.println(Operations.readResult(outcome).asString());
} else {
    System.err.printf("Operation failure: %s%n", Operations.getFailureDescription(outcome));
}
```