# Check programatically if ear in jboss is deployed

Tags: java, jboss, ear

I'm writing a simple monitor webpage which tells (among other things) if an application .ear file is deployed successfully. I implemented this by checking if the deployments directory contains the ear and the .deployed file but 
I ran into problems because the jboss web-deploy installs the ear to another place into a directory with a random generated name. Is there any way to find out if that particular .ear is up and running?

(the monitoring app is a separate .war file in the same jboss)

Comment: Add a simple web resource such as a JSP or a servlet which you can do a HTTP call to?

Comment: take a look in this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16299353/how-to-access-detailed-java-ee-application-deployment-status-on-jboss-as-7

Answer (score 0):

You can get the JMX bean for the application. From there you can get the status of application, servlets, jsp etc.